# Hybrid OpenMP and MPI to accelerate Data Sending

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmp

I am using MPI to send Data to process. I wonder whether OpenMP can accelerate the Data sending.
Here is the background:
The main process (`rank 0`) produce a large `matrix`，and going to send to all the process (including itself).

At first I am tring to using `MPI_Scatterv` and it works, but I think it takes too long. **Then, I use OpenMP to accelerate the data sending, so I change `MPI_Scatterv` to `MPI_Send`**. The simple code is like:

```cpp
double* matrix;
double* local_matrix;
int local_n;
int n;
int comm_sz;
/*...Init matrix, comm_sz and...*/
MPI_Request req_r;
MPI_Irecv(local_matrix, local_n * local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm, &req_r);
if (my_rank == 0)
{
#   pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < comm_sz; ++i)
    {
        int offset = ...;    /*The offset corresponding to start of matrix*/
        MPI_Send(matrix + offset, 1, block_t, i, 0, comm);    /*Send to i_th process with tag = 0*/
    }
}
MPI_Wait(&req_r, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

The `matrix` and `local_matrix` is a one-dimensional array, `comm_sz` is the number of the process, `block_t` is a self-defined MPI_Type, containing `local_n*local_n` double, which represents a submatrix of `matrix`, and the `offset` is the offset corresponding to start of `matrix`.

---

But after experiment, the time cost is bad.

- Only MPI_Scatterv : Almost 1.02 s
- Only MPI_Send : Almost 1.38 s
- OpenMP with MPI_Send: Almost 1.55s

My question is :
1. Why using OpenMP cannot accelerate the MPI_Send?
2. And is there any ways to speed up sending with the help of *multithread*?

PS:
1. When using OpenMP, I already call `MPI_Init_thread`.
2. Using `MPI_Wtime()` to get the whole spending time.

Comment: The outcome depends on the implementation of your  MPI library and your interconnect among other factors. Try using a unique tag per thread, that won’t hurt and might help. If `block_t` is not a contiguous datatype, that can be a bottleneck and you can try packing/unpacking to/from a temporary buffer with OpenMP, and transfer contiguous data.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for your reply. Using a unique tag doesn't seem to work. And you mentions `block_t`, I create it through `MPI_Type_create_subarray()`, I think `block_t` is contiguous in some degree. The background is I am trying to send  the submatrix of `matrix` to other process. For example, a 4*4 matrix, and I am trying to send four 2*2 submatrix to four process.

Comment: yep, I think I got that. The point is data will be packed/unpacked under the hood by MPI in order to be sent/received, and this process is generally sequential, that is why you can speed it up by doing manual packing in parallel with all your OpenMP threads. Keep in mind some implementations are a bit slower with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, and this is no more a requirement if MPI is not invoked in a parallel region.

Comment: My bad for suggesting a unique tag per thread, I clearly misread your code.

Comment: You should measure the bandwidth you achieve with a single thread on the root task, and compare it to the theoretical bandwidth your hardware can achieve. If you are close to that limit, then you are limited by your network and using more threads will not help.